# can I use gps from phone for my laptop

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I would like to know if is it possible to use gps module from my phone in my laptop.

I want to write an application (Windows 8 Metro) that uses geolocalization but my PC doesn not have a gps module. Is there some possibility to use phone as an external gps ?

Comment: Posting as a comment because I'm not answering your original question, but you may find the easiest approach is to use the Simulator in Visual Studio 2012 to run your app, and adjust the location via the "Set Location" button:

  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441475(v=vs.110).aspx

You'll be able to set latitude, longitude, altitude, and accuracy as you wish and the app will have those results returned via calls to the Geolocation API.

Comment: that sounds very helpfull but still having a real gps to test moving,changing position in real time etc would be great

Answer (score 0):

Set up a web service. Create a phone application that will send geolocation data to the service. The service can then either fetch the data to the Metro Style application, or the application can pull the location data at specific time intervals.

Comment: But the question was can i connect phone as external gps device

Comment: Depends on the device. Some phones are able to do it through the Bluetooth layer (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=348120).